# Raven - Sentry and Django: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: django, sentry

I installed raven-python in my django project, the `./manage.py raven test` works, but I get a big traceback when I want to load any page of my app (the development server starts correctly):

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
    signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__, environ=environ)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 201, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/models.py", line 209, in before_request
    self.client.context.activate()
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/models.py", line 55, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda x, o: getattr(get_client(), o)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/models.py", line 135, in get_client
    instance = Client(**options)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/client.py", line 138, in __init__
    Client.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/base.py", line 222, in __init__
    self.hook_libraries(hook_libraries)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/base.py", line 275, in hook_libraries
    hook_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/breadcrumbs.py", line 364, in hook_libraries
    func()
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/utils/__init__.py", line 185, in new_func
    rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vince/.virtualenvs/abelujo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/breadcrumbs.py", line 286, in _hook_requests
    real_send = Session.send
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'`

I don't know where to investigate. Any idea what's going on ? 
Thanks.

[raven/django documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/) (I don't use the client defined at the end of the setup).

---

I use django-whitenoise to serve static files, setted on `wsgi.py` but it does not appear to have any influence (I disabled it).
Django version 1.8, raven v6.0.0.

Raven config:

`RAVEN_CONFIG = {
            'dsn': dsn,
            # If you are using git, you can also automatically configure the
            # release based on the git info.
            'release': raven.fetch_git_sha(os.path.dirname(os.pardir)),
        }`

My middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',  # for intcomma currency filter only (card show).
    'django_extensions',
    'bootstrap3',
    'bootstrap_admin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Custom:
    'mod_wsgi.server',
    'huey.contrib.djhuey',
    'rest_framework',
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',  # sentry
    'search', # my app
)
```

my wsig.py:

`from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)`

---

**update** I had the same problem with unit tests. I eventually prevented from adding sentry to the INSTALLED_APPS in debug mode:

```
if PROD:
    INSTALLED_APPS += 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat'
```

and loaded the loggers accordingly:

```
def get_logger():
    """Get the appropriate logger for PROD or DEBUG mode. On local
    development, don't use the sentry_logger (throws errors).
    """
    if settings.DEBUG:
        return logging.getLogger('debug_logger')
    else:
        return logging.getLogger('sentry_logger')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the cause of the error message, but I suppose for starters you could install Raven in the middleware or wsgi : https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/#message-references

Comment: thanks or the pointer ! This middleware was no use, but I installed the one at the wsgi level (right after django's `get_wsgi_application` and **before** whitenoise's middleware), and it works. (I suppose if you add a mention of wsgi in your answer I can accept it :) )

Comment: still, if someone could explain…

Comment: If I get the chance, I'll dig around in the Raven source. I suspect it's something related to your wsgi wrapper for whitenoise.

Comment: note that the error message happened also when I deactivated whitenoise's middlewares in wsgi.py.